# Convert Columns to Row Javascript with two rowIndex

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need your help , I have this

[image]

But I need put this in the following table

```
------------------------------------------------------
Name      |   Pernr |  data 1   | date 2  | date3    |
------------------------------------------------------
Nuno      |   000004|  0        | -40     |   -32    |
------------------------------------------------------
Carlos    |   000004|  0        | -40     | -32      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I have this code

```
var result = {}, ret = [];
        var newCols = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
            if (!result[arrayData[i].Pernr]) {
                result[arrayData[i].Pernr] = {};

            }

            result[arrayData[i].Pernr][arrayData[i].WeekBegin] = arrayData[i].DifRegExp;

            //To get column names
            if (newCols.indexOf(arrayData[i].WeekBegin) == -1) {
                newCols.push(arrayData[i].WeekBegin);
            }


        }
```

But I don't know how to store two indices
Can any one help me please ?

Comment: what's `arrayData` and what is `newCols` used for? Can you show us some more code?

Comment: please add the data you have in plain text, and a wanted output.